# If, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\lvert x_{n+1} - x_n \lvert\le a^n$ (for $a\in (0,1)$), then $x_n\to x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, cauchy-sequences

Consider $\{x_n\}$, a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, and suppose that $\exists a \in (0,1)$ such that $\lvert x_{n+1} -x_n \lvert\le a^n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then $x_n \to x$ for some $x\in \mathbb{R}$. $\leftarrow$ This is what needs to be proved.

I'm feeling somewhat puzzled because there's a counterexample, where $x_n = \log n$. So, we know that $0 <a^n < 1 $ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but isn't $\lvert\log(n+1)-\log(n)\lvert \le a^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, while $\{\log(n)\}$ diverges to $+\infty$?

Comment: $\log (n + 1) - \log(n)$ is approximately $\frac{1}{n}$. $a^n$ diminishes much faster for any $a \in (0, 1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$|x_n-x_{n+m}|\leq |x_n-x_{n+1}|+|x_{n+1}-x_{n+2}|+...+|x_{n+m-1}-x_{n+m}|$$
$$\leq a^n+a^{n+1}+...+a^{n+m-1}=a^n(1+a+..+a^{m-1})\leq a^n(1+a+a^2+...)=a^n\frac{1}{1-a}\to 0,\,\forall m\ge 0$$
Therefore $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy and thus converges.

Comment: What is the difference between the RHS and LHS in $a^n(1+a+..+a^{m-1})\leq a^n(1+a+a^2+...)$? @Svetoslav

Comment: The difference is that the second sum is infinite and there we use the geometric series formula. For why it is Cauchy, because for any $\epsilon>0$ you can find $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ to have $\frac{a^n}{1-a}\leq \epsilon$, so this gives that for all $n\ge N,\forall m\ge 1:\, |x_n-x_{n+m}|\leq \epsilon$ which is the definition for a sequence being Cauchy.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $n<m$. Then by triangle inequality and by your condition
\begin{align*}
|x_m - x_n|&\leq \sum_{k=n}^{m-1}|x_{k+1}-x_k|\leq \sum_{k=n}^{m-1}a^{k}= \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}a^{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{k}=\frac{1-a^{m}}{1-a}-\frac{1-a^{n}}{1-a}=\frac{a^{n}-a^{m}}{1-a}.
\end{align*}
Can you show that this implies that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$? Thus has a limit?

Also, regarding your counter-example, note that
\begin{align*}
|\log(n+1)-\log(n)|&=|\log(1+\frac{1}{n})|\to 0
\end{align*}
as $n\to \infty$, but the decay is not exponential. The series expansion of $\ln$ for $|x|\leq 1$ is 
\begin{align*}
\ln(1+x)&=x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3}+O(x^4).
\end{align*}

Comment: How is it justified that $|x_m - x_n|\leq \sum_{k=n}^{m-1}|x_{k+1}-x_k|$ and that $\sum_{k=n}^{m-1}a^{k}= \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}a^{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{k}$ (how are you assigning these indices in this case)?

Also, I can see that $|x_{n+1}-x_n|$ participates in the summation as one of the terms, but how is it relevant to the proof? Sorry, I'm simply not that advanced.

Comment: The second part of my question is no longer needed :) @T.Eskin

Comment: @sequence. The first inequality is triangle inequality applied $m-n$ times and the equality after that is just expressing the partial sum from $n$ to $m-1$ as the difference of the same sum by noticing that it is the same as from $0$ to $m-1$ minus from $0$ to $n-1$. Then just use the geometric series formula.